# Export to KML option using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, kml

I am very new to this GIS thing.

I have to integrate export to KML option in one of my project.

I could not see this option while googling.

Is there option to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet.draw vector editing handlers</title>

    <script src="libs/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="../src/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.draw.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/NavBar/Leaflet.NavBar.css" />

    <script src="../src/Toolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Tooltip.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/ext/GeometryUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/LatLngUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/LineUtil.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/Polygon.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/Polyline.Intersect.js"></script>


    <script src="../src/draw/DrawToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Feature.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Marker.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Polygon.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Rectangle.js"></script>


    <script src="../src/edit/EditToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Edit.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Delete.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/Control.Draw.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/NavBar/Leaflet.NavBar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Poly.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Rectangle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Marker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="plotAccidents();">plot accidents</button><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearAccidents();">clear accidents</button><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="addWMS();">Add WMS</button><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="panTo();">Pan To Address</button><br/>

WKT String : <span id="wktstring"></span>
    <script>
        var bounds;
        var plotbounds;
        var count=0;
        var checked =1;
        var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
            map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(47.58, 29.22), zoom: 13}),
            drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

        var markers = new L.FeatureGroup(); 
        map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
            edit: { featureGroup: drawnItems }
        }));

        map.on('draw:created', function(event) {
            var layer = event.layer;

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });
        L.control.navbar().addTo(map);

        function plotAccidents()
        {
            populate();
            map.addLayer(markers);
        }
        function clearAccidents()
        {
            map.removeLayer(markers);
        }

        function getRandomLatLng(map) {

        //if(bounds==null)
        bounds = map.getBounds();
        if(count==0)
        {
        console.log(bounds);

        }
        //if(count==0)
        //{
            //console.log("southWest");
            //console.log(bounds.getSouthWest());
        //}
        southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
        northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
        lngSpan = northEast.lng - southWest.lng;
        latSpan = northEast.lat - southWest.lat;
    count++;
    return new L.LatLng(
    southWest.lat + latSpan * Math.random(),
    southWest.lng + lngSpan * Math.random());
    }

    function populate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var point = getRandomLatLng(map);

        if(plotbounds!=null && !plotbounds.contains(point))
        continue;
        var marker = L.marker(point);
        marker.bindPopup("<p>Accident details goes here</p>", {
            showOnMouseOver: true
        });
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
    return false;
}
function toWKT(layer) {
    var lng, lat, coords = [];

    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon || layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
        var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
        for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
            latlngs[i]
            coords.push(latlngs[i].lng + " " + latlngs[i].lat);
            if (i === 0) {
                lng = latlngs[i].lng;
                lat = latlngs[i].lat;
            }
    };
        if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
            return "POLYGON((" + coords.join(",") + "," + lng + " " + lat + "))";
        } else if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
            return "LINESTRING(" + coords.join(",") + ")";
        }
    } else if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        return "POINT(" + layer.getLatLng().lng + " " + layer.getLatLng().lat + ")";
    }
}
var drawnItems = new L.LayerGroup();
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType; 

    plotbounds = e.layer.getBounds();
    console.log(plotbounds);
    var layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    document.getElementById('wktstring').innerHTML=(toWKT(layer));
});



map.addLayer(drawnItems);
function addWMS()
{
    L.tileLayer.wms("http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000',
    format: 'image/png',
    version: '1.1.0',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "",
    tiled:true
}).addTo(map);
}
function panTo()
{
    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 8):

Indirectly, using [tokml](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml), after first converting to geojson:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- include this from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/tokml/master/tokml.js -->
    <script src="tokml.js"></script>

    <script>
        // set up a basic map and add a marker
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.11]).addTo(map);

        // convert marker to geojson
        // layers also have a toGeoJSON function
        var json = marker.toGeoJSON();

        // then export to kml
        var kml = tokml(json);
    </script>
</body>
```

the kml that results from the above operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData></ExtendedData>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-0.11,51.5</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

**Update:**

If it is `drawnItems` that you want to convert to kml, you can use [toGeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-togeojson) on the `featureGroup`:

```
var json = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
var kml = tokml(json);
```

This works layers with mixed geometries (points, lines, polygons).

I don't know where it makes the most sense for you to do this in your code. `drawnItems` is declared in global scope, so you could do this in `draw.on('created')`, or in a new function triggered by an export button (for example).

Comment: thank you. i need to conver a layer which contains multiple shapes.

Comment: can you post some code in your question? At least how you are creating the data and adding it to the map.

Comment: i have added the code. I thought first to convert the layer to geojson. but could n't find any option. can you pls give any suggestion like how ot proceed. I have scene the same option available in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

I am looking at the same issue.
Firstly Converting to geoJSON and then KML.  This tokml looks promising and seems to work.
First problem is geoJSON does not recognise Circles, so i needed a workaround foir that - found on another thread.

### So what I am doing.

In need a function to replace circle shapes with calculated polygons when added.
Then a function to generate geoJSON, ( i assigned to a button ).
The simply posing the geoJSON tokml.
Here is my version of the process.
I fire shapes1 on a button when i have finished 
$('#textareashowinggeojson').val(shapes1).select();

### From there you can simply run tokml with that textarea or simply the value returned from shapes1

```
    function createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, sides, rotation, projection) {

        var latlon = origin; //leaflet equivalent
        var angle;
        var new_lonlat, geom_point;
        var points = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
            angle = (i * 360 / sides) + rotation;
            new_lonlat = destinationVincenty(latlon, angle, radius); 
            geom_point = L.latLng(new_lonlat.lng, new_lonlat.lat); 

            points.push(geom_point); 
        }   

        return points; 
    };
    L.Util.VincentyConstants = {
        a: 6378137,
        b: 6356752.3142,
        f: 1/298.257223563  
    };  
    function destinationVincenty(lonlat, brng, dist) { //rewritten to work with leaflet

        var u = L.Util;
        var ct = u.VincentyConstants;
        var a = ct.a, b = ct.b, f = ct.f;
        var lon1 = lonlat.lng;
        var lat1 = lonlat.lat;
        var s = dist;
        var pi = Math.PI;
        var alpha1 = brng * pi/180 ; //converts brng degrees to radius
        var sinAlpha1 = Math.sin(alpha1);
        var cosAlpha1 = Math.cos(alpha1);
        var tanU1 = (1-f) * Math.tan( lat1 * pi/180 /* converts lat1 degrees to radius */ ); 
        var cosU1 = 1 / Math.sqrt((1 + tanU1*tanU1)), sinU1 = tanU1*cosU1;
        var sigma1 = Math.atan2(tanU1, cosAlpha1);
        var sinAlpha = cosU1 * sinAlpha1;
        var cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha*sinAlpha;
        var uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a*a - b*b) / (b*b);
        var A = 1 + uSq/16384*(4096+uSq*(-768+uSq*(320-175*uSq)));
        var B = uSq/1024 * (256+uSq*(-128+uSq*(74-47*uSq)));
        var sigma = s / (b*A), sigmaP = 2*Math.PI;
        while (Math.abs(sigma-sigmaP) > 1e-12) {
            var cos2SigmaM = Math.cos(2*sigma1 + sigma);
            var sinSigma = Math.sin(sigma);
            var cosSigma = Math.cos(sigma);
            var deltaSigma = B*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+B/4*(cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)-
                B/6*cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*sinSigma*sinSigma)*(-3+4*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));
            sigmaP = sigma;
            sigma = s / (b*A) + deltaSigma;
        }
        var tmp = sinU1*sinSigma - cosU1*cosSigma*cosAlpha1;
        var lat2 = Math.atan2(sinU1*cosSigma + cosU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1,
            (1-f)*Math.sqrt(sinAlpha*sinAlpha + tmp*tmp));
        var lambda = Math.atan2(sinSigma*sinAlpha1, cosU1*cosSigma - sinU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1);
        var C = f/16*cosSqAlpha*(4+f*(4-3*cosSqAlpha));
        var lam = lambda - (1-C) * f * sinAlpha *
            (sigma + C*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+C*cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));  
        var revAz = Math.atan2(sinAlpha, -tmp);  // final bearing
        var lamFunc = lon1 + (lam * 180/pi); //converts lam radius to degrees
        var lat2a = lat2 * 180/pi; //converts lat2a radius to degrees

        return L.latLng(lamFunc, lat2a);

    };

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'circle') {

            var origin = layer.getLatLng(); //center of drawn circle
            var radius = layer.getRadius(); //radius of drawn circle
            var projection = L.CRS.EPSG4326;
            var polys = createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, 60, 0, projection); //these are the points that make up the circle
            var polygon = []; // store the geometry
            for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
                var geometry = [polys[i].lat, polys[i].lng]; 
                polygon.push(geometry);
            }
            var cpolygon = L.polygon(polygon);
            drawnItems.addLayer(cpolygon);
        } else {
            //Just do as normal
            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        }
    });

    var getShapes1 = function(drawnItems) {
        var shapes1 = JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
        return shapes1;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly grabbed your and slapped up something.
You seem to have redeclared the drawnitems further on - not sure why
Function at the bottom of the javascript should get you what you need.

### genKml()

```
    var bounds;
    var plotbounds;
    var count=0;
    var checked =1;
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
        map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(47.58, 29.22), zoom: 13}),
        drawnItems;

    var markers = new L.FeatureGroup(); 


    drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            circle: true, 
            polygon: {allowIntersection: false}                    
        },
        edit: { featureGroup: drawnItems }
    }));

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'circle') {

            var origin = layer.getLatLng(); //center of drawn circle
            var radius = layer.getRadius(); //radius of drawn circle
            var projection = L.CRS.EPSG4326;
            var polys = createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, 60, 0, projection); //these are the points that make up the circle
            var polygon = []; // store the geometry
            for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
                var geometry = [polys[i].lat, polys[i].lng]; 
                polygon.push(geometry);
            }
            var cpolygon = L.polygon(polygon);
            drawnItems.addLayer(cpolygon);
        } else {

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        }
    });


    var getShapes = function(drawnItems) {
        var shapes = JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
        return shapes;
    };


    L.control.navbar().addTo(map);

    function plotAccidents()
    {
        populate();
        map.addLayer(markers);
    }
    function clearAccidents()
    {
        map.removeLayer(markers);
    }

    function getRandomLatLng(map) {

    //if(bounds==null)
    bounds = map.getBounds();
    if(count==0)
    {
    console.log(bounds);

    }
    //if(count==0)
    //{
        //console.log("southWest");
        //console.log(bounds.getSouthWest());
    //}
    southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    lngSpan = northEast.lng - southWest.lng;
    latSpan = northEast.lat - southWest.lat;
count++;
return new L.LatLng(
southWest.lat + latSpan * Math.random(),
southWest.lng + lngSpan * Math.random());
}

function populate() {
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var point = getRandomLatLng(map);

    if(plotbounds!=null && !plotbounds.contains(point))
    continue;
    var marker = L.marker(point);
    marker.bindPopup("<p>Accident details goes here</p>", {
        showOnMouseOver: true
    });
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
return false;
```

}
function toWKT(layer) {
    var lng, lat, coords = [];

```
if (layer instanceof L.Polygon || layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
    var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
    for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
        latlngs[i]
        coords.push(latlngs[i].lng + " " + latlngs[i].lat);
        if (i === 0) {
            lng = latlngs[i].lng;
            lat = latlngs[i].lat;
        }
};
    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        return "POLYGON((" + coords.join(",") + "," + lng + " " + lat + "))";
    } else if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
        return "LINESTRING(" + coords.join(",") + ")";
    }
} else if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    return "POINT(" + layer.getLatLng().lng + " " + layer.getLatLng().lat + ")";
}
```

}

```
    function createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, sides, rotation, projection) {

        var latlon = origin; //leaflet equivalent
        var angle;
        var new_lonlat, geom_point;
        var points = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
            angle = (i * 360 / sides) + rotation;
            new_lonlat = destinationVincenty(latlon, angle, radius); 
            geom_point = L.latLng(new_lonlat.lng, new_lonlat.lat); 

            points.push(geom_point); 
        }   

        return points; 
    };
    L.Util.VincentyConstants = {
        a: 6378137,
        b: 6356752.3142,
        f: 1/298.257223563  
    };  
    function destinationVincenty(lonlat, brng, dist) { //rewritten to work with leaflet

        var u = L.Util;
        var ct = u.VincentyConstants;
        var a = ct.a, b = ct.b, f = ct.f;
        var lon1 = lonlat.lng;
        var lat1 = lonlat.lat;
        var s = dist;
        var pi = Math.PI;
        var alpha1 = brng * pi/180 ; //converts brng degrees to radius
        var sinAlpha1 = Math.sin(alpha1);
        var cosAlpha1 = Math.cos(alpha1);
        var tanU1 = (1-f) * Math.tan( lat1 * pi/180 /* converts lat1 degrees to radius */ ); 
        var cosU1 = 1 / Math.sqrt((1 + tanU1*tanU1)), sinU1 = tanU1*cosU1;
        var sigma1 = Math.atan2(tanU1, cosAlpha1);
        var sinAlpha = cosU1 * sinAlpha1;
        var cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha*sinAlpha;
        var uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a*a - b*b) / (b*b);
        var A = 1 + uSq/16384*(4096+uSq*(-768+uSq*(320-175*uSq)));
        var B = uSq/1024 * (256+uSq*(-128+uSq*(74-47*uSq)));
        var sigma = s / (b*A), sigmaP = 2*Math.PI;
        while (Math.abs(sigma-sigmaP) > 1e-12) {
            var cos2SigmaM = Math.cos(2*sigma1 + sigma);
            var sinSigma = Math.sin(sigma);
            var cosSigma = Math.cos(sigma);
            var deltaSigma = B*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+B/4*(cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)-
                B/6*cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*sinSigma*sinSigma)*(-3+4*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));
            sigmaP = sigma;
            sigma = s / (b*A) + deltaSigma;
        }
        var tmp = sinU1*sinSigma - cosU1*cosSigma*cosAlpha1;
        var lat2 = Math.atan2(sinU1*cosSigma + cosU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1,
            (1-f)*Math.sqrt(sinAlpha*sinAlpha + tmp*tmp));
        var lambda = Math.atan2(sinSigma*sinAlpha1, cosU1*cosSigma - sinU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1);
        var C = f/16*cosSqAlpha*(4+f*(4-3*cosSqAlpha));
        var lam = lambda - (1-C) * f * sinAlpha *
            (sigma + C*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+C*cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));  
        var revAz = Math.atan2(sinAlpha, -tmp);  // final bearing
        var lamFunc = lon1 + (lam * 180/pi); //converts lam radius to degrees
        var lat2a = lat2 * 180/pi; //converts lat2a radius to degrees

        return L.latLng(lamFunc, lat2a);

    };
```

var drawnItems = new L.LayerGroup();
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType;

```
plotbounds = e.layer.getBounds();
console.log(plotbounds);
var layer = e.layer;
drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
document.getElementById('wktstring').innerHTML=(toWKT(layer));
```

});

map.addLayer(drawnItems);
function addWMS()
{
    L.tileLayer.wms("http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000',
    format: 'image/png',
    version: '1.1.0',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "",
    tiled:true
}).addTo(map);
}
function panTo()
{
    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));
}

function genKml() {
    var myJSONdata = getShapes(drawnItems);
    run(JSON.parse(myJSONdata));
};

```
<script src='../src/site/site.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to that simply include the tokml.js file 
Then this will generate the kml.  JSON.parse is required for tokml to work.
the options for tokml documentname documentdescription simplestyle are optional

```
var kshapes = JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON());
    var kmlDoc = tokml(JSON.parse(kshapes), {
        documentName: 'My Polygons',
        documentDescription: 'Some stuff I drew', 
        simplestyle: true
    });
```

I am then going to post the results in a form to another page to generate a file to download.